# Error installing Google Analytics in iOS with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods

I'm trying to install Google Analytics via cocoa pods, but it's not possible, I always get this error:

```
Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Google/Analytics (~> 1.0.0)` required by `Podfile`

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:388:in `handle_resolver_error'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:69:in `rescue in resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:56:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:535:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:533:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:70:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:210:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:133:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:132:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:104:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:71:in `run_install_with_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:101:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

My podfile already contains different pods and a private pod:

```
platform :ios, "6.0"

source 'git@github.com:MyCompany/myCompany-cocoaPods-ios.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target "MyTarget" do

pod 'OpenWeatherMapAPI', '~> 0.0.5'
pod 'INCore', '~>1.1.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '>= 1.3.1'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'

end
```

Any ideas what I can try? Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using iOS 7.0 as the deployment target in your project build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Change your platform in podfile to ios 7.0 or above :

```
platform :ios, "7.0"
```

If you are using iOS 6 or earlier, you can use this pod :

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '3.13.0'
```